# Table column sizing involving colspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I managed to kinda achieve my intended design but it feels kinda like a hack.

So I'm working with this table and now cell size looks exactly as I'd like it to be, but I have to add extra row on top of my table (and hide it, but not in example so it's easier to understand). So if you try and delete that top row you can see how it all gets messed up (description fields don't look the same).

http://jsfiddle.net/nooorz24/cea57mhd/4/

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 10000px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 1px;"></td>
        <td style="width: 10000px;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 1px;">IMG</td>
        <td style="width: 10000px;" colspan="2">Description text</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td style="width: 1px;">IMG</td>
        <td style="width: 10000px;">Description text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As far as I can understand it's because I try to set width to a cell that has colspan="2" and html doesn't understand how to work with that.

Can this be solved without adding extra row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the HTML [`col`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) element which is designed just for that: styling or defining common attributes for an entire column.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 1px">
    <col style="width: 10000px;">
    <col style="width: 1px">
    <col style="width: 10000px;">
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>IMG</td>
    <td colspan="2">Description text</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td>IMG</td>
    <td>Description text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```